# SQL Order By but invert for one element

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got an SQL query which results upto the following

```
Code  int1 int2 int3   S
C12      21   22   14  1
C33      43   56   2   3
C34      23   2    1   3
C55      33   92   12  5
CB56     45   66   10  5
MA10     10   11   12  1
```

This is the result of using OrderBy on Code
However I do not want it to order according to alphabets
But by the number after it for ex 1 in M1 and 33 in C33
In some cases the number after the alphabet may be 3 digits like E344
What I want it to look like

```
Code  int1 int2 int3    S
MA10     10   11   12   1
C12      21   22   14   1
C323     43   56   2    3
C325     43   56   2    3
C34      23   2    1    3
C525     33   92   12   5
CB56     45   66   10   5
```

What I need is

M Should always show on top if Present
Then Sort According to Number on first place
Then Sort it according to the number on the Second place
Then sort it according to the number on the third place

The field 's' will always consist of the first digit from the Code

Comment: if you're code field is always 1 text character, simply take mid for length -1 starting at 1 and cast it to numeric. in your order by.  The fact you want M on top assumes 1 character so `order by substring(code,1,1) desc, substring(code,2) *1` but again assumes 1st character is all we need to consider.

Comment: pardon me, but my code field may contain two letters as well,

Comment: Burned by incomplete sample data again. So is code limited to 5 characters then? 1(maybe 2) character data and up to 3 numbers? and do you want it in reverse alphabetical order or what order should the CODE be sorted in AFTer the M?

Comment: Yeah, Upto minimum 1 character maximum 2 and minimum 2 numbers and maximum 3

Comment: M should always be the first result,  after M, It should be ascending on alphabets followed by the number on the first place followed by the number on the second place followed by the number on the third place

Comment: So Code M9 would come after M10? Since 1 come before 9 or are we looking at the entire number set?

Comment: extract the number from string, then use in order by

Comment: @piyush much more complicated than that.

Comment: @xQbert Yes,That's exactly how it should be

Comment: @xQbert but it would be more full proof solution

Comment: @Piyush It's more like extracting the first digit then order and then extracting the second digit and then order and then extracting the third digit and then order.

Comment: @user3425867:- no, just extract the numeric value from code MA10 or M9 say 9 or 10 then make order form that. That should be the logic as per mine

Comment: @piyush but that's not what is desired. M9 comes AFTER M10 not before. because 1<9 each numeric value is independent of the next

Comment: @xQbert :- ohhh i didn't notice that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**step 1** split up the column into 2 columns, 1 containing the letters, the other containing the numbers:

```
SELECT 
  substring(code,0,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Code)) as letters,
  substring(code,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Code)) as numbers,
  fields
FROM table
```

**step 2** Convert the numbers to integer and sort

```
CONVERT(substring(code,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Code)),UNSIGNED INTEGER) as numbers
```

**step 3** sort

```
Order by field1 asc, field2 desc... etc
```

It might be easier to use a subquery:

```
select * from
  (SELECT 
    substring(code,0,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Code)) as letters,
     CONVERT(substring(code,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Code)),UNSIGNED INTEGER) as numbers,
    fields
  FROM table) T
order by numbers asc, letters desc
```

Comment: Doesn't take into account M 1st, nor the fact that numbers have to be sorted on their own 1st number to 1st number so multiple field have to be broken out.  Right concept though.

Comment: Yeah, didnt really felt like doing someones (home)work. This site should help you when you get stuck. I think in this answer i didnt give a complete answer, but provided enough direction to get him/her back on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

This is conceptually simple: you want to order first by whether the code starts or not with the letter 'M', and then by the numeric portion of the code. You say in a comment:

> extracting the first digit then order and then extracting the second
>   digit and then order and then extracting the third digit and then
>   order

This is exactly how alphabetical order has always worked. You order by first character; when it is the same you order by the second character, etc. so you need no special treatment for that case. Just get the numeric part of the code *as a string*, then order by it.

At this point, the only problem left to resolve is how to extract the numeric part of the code. That would be easy with `PATINDEX()` (as Alfons pointed out) but unfortunately MySQL does not support `PATINDEX()` as far as I know.

Now, what follows is extremely ugly, but it does work. Basically we get the non-numeric part of the string by removing all the numeric characters from it, then use the length of the non-numeric part to extract the numeric part.

```sql
SELECT mytable.* FROM mytable
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        code,
        RIGHT(code, LENGTH(letters)) numbers
    FROM (
        SELECT 
        code,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
            REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
            code, 0, ''), 1, ''), 2, ''), 3, ''), 4, '')
            , 5, ''), 6, ''), 7, ''), 8, ''), 9, '') letters
        FROM mytable
        ) letters_table
) numbers_table
ON numbers_table.code = mytable.code
ORDER BY (numbers_table.code like 'M%') DESC,
    numbers_table.numbers ASC
```

This solution is probably inefficient. However, I don't think you can get any acceptable efficiency anyway unless you store the numeric part on a separate column that you can index.

Answer (score 0):

As you are guaranteeing that s is the value of the first digit in the code, this can be used to find the start of the code and from there, get the numeric part of the code. As you want to have all the codes starting with 'M' first, this results in the following `ORDER BY` clause:

```
... ORDER BY IF(SUBSTR(code, 1, 1) = 'M', 0, 1), SUBSTR(code, LOCATE(s, code))
```